# HttpSession is cleared after another thread calls RMI

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, rmi

My app uses Spring Security (4.2.1.RELEASE), i have a problem with one request, during that request my app calls other app using RMI (using Spring's `RmiProxyFactoryBean`). During that call, i can see in the logs, RMI thread doesn't have info about `SecurityContext` and clears current `HttpSession`

It happens when `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` calls `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.saveContext`

```
[2017-09-05T17:24:32,759] [RMI TCP Connection(4)-10.200.61.22] [DEBUG][HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper] - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
```

After this, user is not authenticated anymore.

How to overcome this?  Should i attach `SecurityContext` to RMI thread somehow?  or maybe (easier way?)  exclude RMI call from security chain (RMI calls don't have any auth).
and why RMI calls go thru 'web' security filter chain ?

Previously WebApp worked with Spring Security 3.0.5, problem occurred after upgrading to newer one.